# CreateWindow class method throwing expected a type specifier - windows.h

Tags: c++

Take the following code:

```
# pragma once

// Windows specific files
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include "IOS.h"

namespace PlatformGameEngine
{
    class OSWindows : public IOS
    {
    public:
        virtual void CreateWindow( const WindowProperties windowProperties ) override;
    };
}
```

If i remove the `#include <windows.h>` the code compiles fine. If i keep it in, I get an error pop up under the virtual void CreateWindow part...

> expected a type specifier

What's going on here? How do i solve it?

Comment: I would isolate the windows specific code.

Comment: I bet if you change the method name to CreateWindowA or CreateWindowW you will get the same error message. What you have encountered is a quirk of the Win32 API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateWindow` is an evil macro. If you include the header that defines it, you can't use the name for any other purpose.

Either stop supporting Microsoft or, if you really must do that, choose a different name for your function. Or maybe add `#undef CreateWindow` and hope for the best.

Comment: Lmfao... Insane! - Loll at latest edit. I can't understand how a macro can intefere with genuine class code. I find that to be a bit of a shocking language feature.